# Visual Studio 2010 maximize code window shortcut

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I am looking for the short cut to maximizing code window.. this can be done by first making the window 'float' then clicking on the maximize icon on top right of the window.. I am not able to find the command for the 'maximize' behavior under options/keyboard commands so that i can assign a key combination or find out what the default is..

Comment: There is a full-screen mode, *and* the ability to maximize an individual code window. They're two completely different things—which one are you trying to achieve?

Comment: looking for the maximize for individual code window.. just updated my question to reflect this clearer..

Answer (score 17):

Same <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> does work here as well.

Answer (score 1):

Tools -> Options -> Keyboard -> Use the Window.Float command and bind it to a shortcut.

To return it to being a tabbed document, use the Window.Dock command.

Comment: this is half way through.. need the maximize after float

Answer (score 0):

The thing I was looking for was for the output window, etc. to go away and give all the window back to the text editor (like ^R in SQL Server Management studio.)

This seems to work for me:  Window.AutoHideAll

I'm Using Visual Studio 2013.